Getting an error in console even though I have used try/catch and async/await
/* the code that is doing the API call, account.get() is an endpoint provided by Appwrite to get current user session data */

export async function getCurrentUser() {
  try {
    const user = await account.get(); //api call through appwrite endpoint
    return user;
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log("no user found : ", err);
    return null;
  }
}


/* here I am calling the above async function on a button click */
async function handleClick() {
    try {
      const res = await getCurrentUser();
      console.log(res);
    } 
    catch (err) {
      console.log("error : ", err);
    }
  }

I am using appwrite for my backend. The api request returns a promise as response.
While executing the above code, I am getting an error in the console. I have used try/catch and async/await. I cannot understand why the error is showing up in the console.
I am getting an unauthorized error. My credentials are correct, I have checked. The error happens only if I try to get a current user session before creating a user session. If I have a user session then the error is gone.
I am basically trying to check if a user session exits or not using useEffect() and update a state variable based on that. I am asking why the error is showing up in the console if I have written a "catch" block for it and used "await" also. The catch block message should only be shown in the console according to me.
Image of the error

What error are you getting in the console? We cannot help if we cannot see the error.
It may also help if we could see the code for the api request.

"i am getting an error in the console. I have used try/catch" - And in your catch block(s) you are logging the error to the console.  It's not clear to me what you're asking.  What exactly gets logged to the console?

I am getting an unauthorized error. My credentials are correct, I have checked. The error happens only if I try to get a current user session before creating a user session. If I have a user session then the error is gone.
I am basically trying to check if a user session exit or not using useEffect() and update a state variable base on that.
I am asking why the error is showing up in the console if I have written a "catch" block for it and used "await" also. The catch block message should only be shown in the console according to me.

In that case we would need to see the code that is doing the api call, as you may have something in there that is logging out an error.
But we need to see the console errors as well, as it is difficult to help debug the code without this, so please get a screenshot or copy and paste the logged error into your question

@PratikKumarPatra: What exactly is being logged to the console?  Is what's being logged to the console prefixed with "no user found : " or "error : "?

@Folyik : I have updated the details and added an image of the error. Please check. Let me know if anything else is needed.

@PratikKumarPatra: Do you specifically mean that you want your error logged to the console but not the browser's own error from the AJAX operation?  I wouldn't be surprised if that's internal to the browser and very browser-specific.  (Though I could certainly be mistaken.)  Taking a step back... Why do you need to suppress such error messages?  Perhaps there's a different way to approach whatever the underlying goal is.

@David : I want to know, can try/catch not handle that error message(error message from browser). I just want my own error message to be displayed and not the error message from browser. I am using chrome btw.

@PratikKumarPatra: Your catch block is catching and handling the error.  The output very clearly shows that.  But what's also happening is the browser is logging the error to the console when it happens.  There may be browser-specific settings to change this behavior, or it may be possible to write a browser plugin/extension which modifies this behavior.  But it doesn't sound like those are what you're looking for, is it?  Do you just not want users to see these errors?  They can still see it in the network tab.  What's the specific goal here?

@PratikKumarPatra Are you asking how to get it so that only the error starting with "no user found" is shown, rather than both that and the GET request error showing?

@Folyik: Yes that's what I want.

try this ,
//Global handler
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function (event) {
  console.error('Unhandled rejection (promise: ', event.promise, ', reason: ', event.reason, ').');
});

just for unhandled promise rejections.

I dont think it is possible to catch the network error, as it looks like its written out to the console by code inside the appWrite library.
Ive tried attaching a catch directly to the promise
const user = await account.get().catch(console.log("err"));
But this doesnt work either.
It looks like in AppWrites own documentation that they simply use a catch and allow the network error to be shown in the console.
